# "Missing Operand." Nothing is working

Tags: batch-file, math, cmd

I'm newish to programming .bat files, and I'm making a game that requires adding and subtracting variables.  Any help would be appreciated?  You can see my code below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title Beta Mosquito
color 0A
if "%1" neq "" ( goto %1)
pause
goto Fight
:Stats
SET /a shp=6
SET /a atk=2
SET /a spd=2
SET /a def=2
SET /a chp=6
SET /a charatk=6
:Fight
echo MISSINGTEXTURE
echo 1. Attack
echo 2. Run
set /p answer=Type the number of your option and press enter.
if %answer%==1 SET /a "chp=%shp%-%charatk%"
echo %chp%
pause
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure you copied it correctly and didn't leave any parts out?

Comment: I just put in the rest of the code, I didn't think it was needed but if it helps it is there.

Comment: Yep, that was a pretty crucial missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `@echo off` to `@echo on`, you can see that the `set` statement in the `if %answer%==1` line is trying to be executed as

```
if 1 == 1 set /a "chp=-"
```

This is a result of you never actually going into the `:Stats` section of the code and skipping directly to `:Fight` instead. Remove `goto Fight` and `%chp%` will correctly get set to 0.

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Comment: @LordBobbiousX - Happy to help; if my solution solved your problem, please click the check mark next to my answer to mark it as accepted.